# Recursion: Find lowest minimum payment

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use recursion and bisection search to calculate the minimum monthly payment needed to pay off a loan after 1 year. My code goes too low (for the balance given,the correct answer should be 29157.09), and I can't figure out why. I've tried adjusting all the variables with no luck, I'm just not seeing where the logic error is.

Here's the code:

```
def lowestMinPaymt(bal, int, lbound, ubound):
    def eval_year(bal, int, pay, mnth=12):
        bal = (bal - pay) + ((bal - pay) * (int))
        return bal if mnth <= 0 else eval_year(bal, int, pay, mnth - 1)

    pay = (lbound + ubound) / 2
    b = eval_year(bal, int, pay)
    print("LOWEST PAYMENT CALLED")
    print(f'\nB: {b}\nINT: {round(int, 4)}\nPAY: {pay}\nL: {round(lbound, 4)}\nH: {round(ubound, 4)}\n')

    if -0.02 <= b <= 0.02:
        print(f'Pay within threshold, returning: {pay}')
        return round(pay, 2)
    elif b < -0.02:
        print(f'\n\tBalance overpaid, decreasing pay guess: PAY: {round(pay, 4)} L: {round(lbound, 4)} H: {pay}\n')
        return lowestMinPaymt(bal, int, lbound, pay)
    elif b > 0.02:
        print(f'\n\tBalance underpaid, increasing pay guess: L: {round(lbound, 4)} H: {pay}\n')
        return lowestMinPaymt(bal, int, pay, ubound)
    '''
    return pay if -0.02 <= b <= 0.02 else \
        lowestMinPaymt(bal, int, lbound, pay) if b < -0.02 else \
        lowestMinPaymt(bal, int, pay, ubound)
    '''
bal = 320000
int = 0.2
print(lowestMinPaymt(bal, int / 12, lbound = bal / 12, ubound = bal))
```

Output:

```
LOWEST PAYMENT CALLED

B: 1.3938913907531363
INT: 0.0167
PAY: 27129.783630371094
L: 27129.6438
H: 27129.9235


    Balance underpaid, increasing pay guess: L: 27129.6438 H: 27129.783630371094

LOWEST PAYMENT CALLED

B: 0.37124559969306575
INT: 0.0167
PAY: 27129.853566487633
L: 27129.7836
H: 27129.9235


    Balance underpaid, increasing pay guess: L: 27129.7836 H: 27129.853566487633

LOWEST PAYMENT CALLED

B: -0.14007729570936742
INT: 0.0167
PAY: 27129.8885345459
L: 27129.8536
H: 27129.9235


    Balance overpaid, decreasing pay guess: PAY: 27129.8885 L: 27129.8536 H: 27129.8885345459

LOWEST PAYMENT CALLED

B: 0.11558415200664361
INT: 0.0167
PAY: 27129.871050516766
L: 27129.8536
H: 27129.8885


    Balance underpaid, increasing pay guess: L: 27129.8536 H: 27129.871050516766

LOWEST PAYMENT CALLED

B: -0.012246571875402878
INT: 0.0167
PAY: 27129.879792531334
L: 27129.8711
H: 27129.8885

Pay within threshold, returning: 27129.879792531334
27129.88 <- SHOULD BE 29157.09, +/- 1 cent.
```

Comment: why the line `return lowestMinPaymt(bal, int, pay, (lbound + ubound) / 2)`? `pay` and the `(lbound + ubound) / 2` are the same.

Comment: I'm still messing with it, and have edited the code, along with new output. It actually stops this time, whereas previously it fell into infinite recursion. But, the answer is still incorrect, and I can't figure it out either logically or by just guessing and changing different parts of it.